# Searching for user input variable (string) in SQLite using python

Tags: python, sql, search, sqlite

I am trying to search for a username in a table and subsequently find that users password and check it against input so far I have...

```
    def check():
            username = logEntry.get()
            password = passEntry.get()
            curs.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username = VALUES (?);", (username))
            userExists = curs.fetchone()
            if userExists:
                curs.execute("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE password = VALUES (?);",(password))
                passExists = curs.fetchone()
                if passExists:
                    controller.show_frame(look)
            else:
                errorLabel.place(x=0, y=0)

    logButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=check)
    logButton.place(x=320, y=120)

    regButton = tk.Button(self, text="Registration For New Users",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Register))
    regButton.place(x=110, y=120)
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Updated: I am now having trouble with an error saying that column username does not exist, here is what I have so far. @antti-haapala

```
     def check():
            username = logEntry.get()
            password = passEntry.get()
            cursor.execute("SELECT username, password" "FROM logins WHERE username = ?",(username))
            resultrow = cursor.fetchone()
            if resultrow is not None:
                db_username, db_password = resultrow
                if username == db_username and password == db_password:
                    controller.show_frame(look)
```

Comment: you know that anyone could open the local database and change it ?

Comment: How? I am really new to python and sql so help with such this is appreciated

Comment: That I want to say is that a sqlite3 database is simply a file which can be reade and write to anyone as access to your system. For example by writing another python program

Comment: The program will not be for commercial use so this is fine for me, thank you for the information

Answer (score 2):

Your code is faulty. Even if this is really a Tkinter program, and the password checks do not really add to any security, the following should be noted for all readers might not be aware of the implications in your code:

This kind of program would first for the existence of *any* user with the given username, then it would check for the existence of *any* user with the given password, these need not be the same. If you'd use this kind of code in production, I could get into admin account by changing my unrelated user account password to `a` and logging in with `admin`:`a`.

---

Try something  like this instead to ensure that the password that you check belongs to the very user you are checking:

```
results = cursor.execute("SELECT username, password "
                         "FROM logins WHERE username = ?", (username,))
resultrow = cursor.fetchone()
if resultrow is not None:
    db_user, db_password = resultrow
    if username == db_user and password == db_password:
        controller.show_frame(look)
```

---

And do note that storing plain-text passwords is frowned upon; it is preferable to encrypt these with one-way salted password hashing scheme; for example [`passlib`](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/) ([PyPI](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/)) is a good choice.

Comment: (and please hash your passwords)

Comment: I am currently getting an error saying that the column username does not exist when it does I am confused at why this error has occured.

Comment: Perhaps you created an empty database by accident.

Comment: I do not think I did, but can you have a look here is my database and table being created 
createDb = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cursor = createDb.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE logins
            (username TEXT UNIQUE, password TEXT)''')
    createDb.commit()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    None
@antti-haapala